# Finding equivalence classes and quotients

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Q1: A relation $S$ on $\mathbb{N}$ is given by $xSy$ if $x=2^{\alpha}y$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$.

1. Find the equivalence class for the element 2.
2. Find the set of equivalence classes.

Q2: A relation $T$ on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is given by $(a,b)T(c,d)$ if $a+d=b+c$.

1. Find the equivalence class for the element $(2,0)$.
2. Find the set of equivalence classes.

**What I've done for Q1:**

$2=2^{\alpha}y$ so $y=2^{1-\alpha}$ therefore the equivalence class is $[2]_S=\{2^{1-\alpha}|\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}\}$
Then for the set of all classes I've repeated above for some arbitrary $x$ in $\mathbb{N}$. So $\mathbb{N}/S= \{ x*2^{-\alpha}|\alpha \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

Is this correct?

**What I've done for Q2:**

When we have $(2,0)$, $a+d=b+c$ gives $c-d=2$ so $[(2,0)]_T=\{c-d=2|c,d \in \mathbb{N} \}$
however, for the set of classes $\mathbb{N}/T$ I'm not sure how to move forward. $a+d=b+c$ can be rearranged into $a-b=c-d$ which might help as you have $a,b$ on the left and $c,d$ on the right. But don't know where to go from here.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).